# Google Safe Browsing API v2 sample Implementation Android

Tags: android, http-post, safe-browsing

I am trying to implement a Sample application in **Android** which gets the malware and phishing list from safe Browsing API and checks the authenticity of URL, this is client side method, but I am constantly getting 400 (Bad Request) as response code when I am trying to hit the URL.

Searched throughout the internet but couldn't get any sample working code.

Even on Developer's Guide page https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/developers_guide_v2 it is not mentioned how to send the list name correctly in POST request for downloading or updating.

Please help me by providing the correct procedure of how to send list name (if code snippet can be posted, it would be great as I am new to Android.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out that request should end with '\n'. It is common to ignore this. I hope it helps.